# Why does partition tool GParted read the 190GB of data twice when shrink a 250GB partition to 190GB?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

When using GParted to shrink a 250GB partition to 190GB, I thought it will move the 60GB of data back into the 190GB region and call it done.

But instead it reads the 190GB of data twice, the first time taking about 1 hour and the second time for 2 hours.

The question is:

1) how come it touches the 190GB of data instead of the 60GB of data?
2) how come it reads it twice?

**Update:** i am suspecting this: it says "moving /dev/sdb1 to the right and then shrink it to 190GB"... so is that the reason, first it is to shrink the partition to 190GB, and then move it to the right?  So it is not moving to the right and then shrink it, but to shrink it first and move it.  (cannot move first because the original 250GB is the whole hard drive).  Also, why move it to the right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding #2 (reading twice):

If I recall correctly, it performs a read test first.  I think that's to make sure that there are no “surprises” during the actual move (read and write operations).  You don't want to end up with your file system sawn up in two pieces.

Comment: That's correct; if you look in the details of what it's actually doing, it runs non-destructive tests of everything before it actually takes any action.

Answer (score 1):

This might be an answer:  (I found that when all actions are completed)

When "details" in GParted is clicked on, it shows the 2 actions (resize and create new partition), but when the individual action is clicked on, there are more details.  It actually shows that there were operations like "reading /dev/sdb1 for errors and (if possible) fix them".  It actually contains about 14 lines... with the first line "calibrate /dev/sdb1", which might be what the first 10 minutes was about.